# How to make a dataframe selecting columns from a list of dataframes in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have many dataframes in an object called **df.list**. Below is an example of two dataframes:

```
> dput(df.list$GF.1.GULUPA.1.F1)
structure(list(Evaluacion2 = c("5.1", "5.2"), Sistema = c(1, 
1), Fertilizacion = c("F1", "F1"), Asocio = c("GF", "GF"), Cultivo = c("GULUPA", 
"GULUPA"), Bloque = c(1, 1), `Altura de planta` = c(3.3, 5.1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> dput(df.list$MF.1.MORA.1.F1)
structure(list(Evaluacion2 = c("1.1", "1.2", "3.1", "3.2", "4.1", 
"4.2", "5.1", "5.2"), Sistema = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Fertilizacion = c("F1", 
"F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1"), Asocio = c("MF", "MF", 
"MF", "MF", "MF", "MF", "MF", "MF"), Cultivo = c("MORA", "MORA", 
"MORA", "MORA", "MORA", "MORA", "MORA", "MORA"), Bloque = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `Altura de planta` = c(11.3, 11.7, 42, 
62, 57.1, 51.3, 90.1, 70.2)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

[image]

I need to extract the values of the plant height column, label according to the name of the dataframe. As follows:

```
df.a<-select(df.list$GF.1.GULUPA.1.F1, c("Evaluacion2", "Altura de planta")) 
df.b<-select(df.list$MF.1.MORA.1.F1, c("Evaluacion2", "Altura de planta")) 
names(df.a)<-c("Evaluacion2", "GF.1.GULUPA.1.F1 Altura de planta") 
names(df.b)<- c("Evaluacion2", "MF.1.MORA.1.F1 Altura de planta") 
df.j<-df.a%>%full_join(df.b)

> dput(df.j)
structure(list(Evaluacion2 = c("5.1", "5.2", "1.1", "1.2", "3.1", 
"3.2", "4.1", "4.2"), `GF.1.GULUPA.1.F1 Altura de planta` = c(3.3, 
5.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `MF.1.MORA.1.F1 Altura de planta` = c(90.1, 
70.2, 11.3, 11.7, 42, 62, 57.1, 51.3)), row.names = c(NA, -8L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

I need to do that with all the dataframes of the list that is in the **df.list** object. Please, help me.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first use `purrr::list_rbind()` to bind dataframes, it can conveniently store dataframe name in a column of resulting dataframe. From there it's pivoting to wide.

```r
library(dplyr)
df.list <- list(GF.1.GULUPA.1.F1 = GF.1.GULUPA.1.F1, 
                MF.1.MORA.1.F1 = MF.1.MORA.1.F1)
df.list %>% 
  purrr::list_rbind(names_to = "plant") %>% 
  select(-c(Sistema, Fertilizacion, Asocio, Cultivo, Bloque)) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = plant, 
              values_from = `Altura de planta`, 
              names_glue = "{plant} Altura de planta") 
#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#>   Evaluacion2 `GF.1.GULUPA.1.F1 Altura de planta` MF.1.MORA.1.F1 Altura de pla…¹
#>   <chr>                                     <dbl>                          <dbl>
#> 1 5.1                                         3.3                           90.1
#> 2 5.2                                         5.1                           70.2
#> 3 1.1                                        NA                             11.3
#> 4 1.2                                        NA                             11.7
#> 5 3.1                                        NA                             42  
#> 6 3.2                                        NA                             62  
#> 7 4.1                                        NA                             57.1
#> 8 4.2                                        NA                             51.3
#> # ℹ abbreviated name: ¹​`MF.1.MORA.1.F1 Altura de planta`
```

Input data:

```r
GF.1.GULUPA.1.F1 <- structure(list(Evaluacion2 = c("5.1", "5.2"), Sistema = c(
  1,
  1
), Fertilizacion = c("F1", "F1"), Asocio = c("GF", "GF"), Cultivo = c(
  "GULUPA",
  "GULUPA"
), Bloque = c(1, 1), `Altura de planta` = c(3.3, 5.1)), row.names = c(
  NA,
  -2L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


MF.1.MORA.1.F1 <- structure(list(Evaluacion2 = c(
  "1.1", "1.2", "3.1", "3.2", "4.1",
  "4.2", "5.1", "5.2"
), Sistema = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Fertilizacion = c(
  "F1",
  "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1"
), Asocio = c(
  "MF", "MF",
  "MF", "MF", "MF", "MF", "MF", "MF"
), Cultivo = c(
  "MORA", "MORA",
  "MORA", "MORA", "MORA", "MORA", "MORA", "MORA"
), Bloque = c(
  1,
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
), `Altura de planta` = c(
  11.3, 11.7, 42,
  62, 57.1, 51.3, 90.1, 70.2
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

imap(df.list, ~ select(.x, Evaluacion2, `Altura de planta`) |>
       set_names(c("Evaluacion2", paste(.y, "Altura de planta")))) |>
  reduce(full_join)
```

**How it works**

1. `imap` iterates over `df.list` where `.x` is the list element (a data frame in your case) and `.y` is the list name (e.g., "GF.1.GULUPA.1.F1").
2. `select` takes the columns you want and then `set_names` uses `.y` to prefix the list name.
3. `reduce` will iterate over all your lists of data frames and perform a full join and output a single data frame

Note: If you decide to select more than just these two columns a more dynamic option would be rather than set the names for *all* columns, only rename your target column `Altura de planta`. So, replace the `set_names` line with:

```
rename(!!sym(paste(.y, "Altura de planta")) := `Altura de planta`)
```

As mentioned in the comments by @M-- you can also rename directly in the `select` statement for more concise code.

**Output**

```
  Evaluacion2 `GF.1.GULUPA.1.F1 Altura de planta` `MF.1.MORA.1.F1 Altura de planta`
1 5.1                                         3.3                              90.1
2 5.2                                         5.1                              70.2
3 1.1                                        NA                                11.3
4 1.2                                        NA                                11.7
5 3.1                                        NA                                42  
6 3.2                                        NA                                62  
7 4.1                                        NA                                57.1
8 4.2                                        NA                                51.3
```

**Data**

```
df.list <- list(GF.1.GULUPA.1.F1 = structure(list(Evaluacion2 = c("5.1", 
"5.2"), Sistema = c(1, 1), Fertilizacion = c("F1", "F1"), Asocio = c("GF", 
"GF"), Cultivo = c("GULUPA", "GULUPA"), Bloque = c(1, 1), `Altura de planta` = c(3.3, 
5.1)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), MF.1.MORA.1.F1 = structure(list(Evaluacion2 = c("1.1", "1.2", 
"3.1", "3.2", "4.1", "4.2", "5.1", "5.2"), Sistema = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Fertilizacion = c("F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", 
"F1", "F1", "F1", "F1"), Asocio = c("MF", "MF", "MF", "MF", "MF", 
"MF", "MF", "MF"), Cultivo = c("MORA", "MORA", "MORA", "MORA", 
"MORA", "MORA", "MORA", "MORA"), Bloque = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1), `Altura de planta` = c(11.3, 11.7, 42, 62, 57.1, 51.3, 
90.1, 70.2)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")))
```

Comment: ```imap(df.list, ~ select(.x, Evaluacion2, !!paste(.y, "Altura de planta") := `Altura de planta`)) %>% reduce(full_join)```